# Netflix OData API iPhone: Accessing more than just the title

Tags: ios, objective-c, odata, netflix

Netflix just recently announced that they have a new OData API which gives developers access to more of their catalog and is exactly what I've been looking for. Also, on odata.org they have a sample iPhone Objective-C SDK that accesses the Netflix odata API and displays a few movie titles in a `tableview` with a `navigationcontroller`.

http://odataobjc.codeplex.com/

I'm just messing around right now and I would like to access more than just the catalog titles but I have no idea how to. Preferably, I would like to just push another view controller that will implement a page that can display the synopsis etc. Any suggestions on how to access the other data elements of a movie?

Answer (score 2):

What do you mean that you cant access anything else than the title? Synopsis can be retrieved like this

http://odata.netflix.com/Catalog/Titles('13dk1')/Synopsis

or if you want the synopsis and name of a movie you can use

http://odata.netflix.com/Catalog/Titles('13dk1')?$select=Name,Synopsis

or you can combine it with the Filter operator like this

http://odata.netflix.com/Catalog/Titles?$filter=Name%20eq%20'Avatar'&$select=Name,Synopsis